In Pandoc + Beamer how to remove red box from internal link in footer?
Making slides using markdown in Pandoc with Beamer. In the Madrid and Dresden Beamer themes a hyperlink to the title page is created in the slide footer. On some PDF viewers (e.g. qpdfview) this hyperlink has a red border around it. Some PDF viewers do not show the red box (xpdf, firefox, vs code). How can I remove that red border?
Other answers say to do something like:
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

or
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue}

I've put this in the Pandoc YAML preamble, but it has no effect:
hyperrefoptions:
  - hidelinks

Edit: Minimal example (including a workaround):
---
title: Getting rid of the red box
author:
  - Glenn R
institute:
  - The office
date: August 2024
theme: Madrid
# Uncomment below to disable links to get rid of the red border around the footer link
#hyperrefoptions:
#  - draft
---

# Slide One
## Content One
- A
- B

# Slide Two
Content 2

Build using
pandoc -t beamer -f markdown redbox.md -o redbox.pdf


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've included an example and further info. No idea about necessary packages, etc, because I'm using pandoc so I don't have to be concerned about that.

Thanks for your update. I just tried your example and don't get a red box. Is your pandoc etc. up-to-date?

The red box doesn't appear in all PDF viewers. The one I'm using, qpfdview, does show it.

The red boxes aren't related to pandoc or beamer, qpdfview adds them. You can switch this off in the settings by deselecting Decorate links:


The links can be disabled with the following option in the Pandoc YAML preamble:
---
...
hyperrefoptions:
  - draft
...
---

A side effect of this is that the red borders disappear. That the links are also disabled doesn't matter in my use case.
